# Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'newExerciseDelegate'

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I've searched for a solution to this problem, even tried following a few tutorials to try to solve this, but for some reason I'm ending up with the same issue. I'm attempting to pass a custom object to a different view controller, but every time I try I get the error "Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'newExerciseDelegate'"

My delegate:

```
protocol exerciseDelegate {
func savedExercise(newExercise: Exercise)
```

}

my sending VC uses the following code:

```
var newExerciseDelegate: exerciseDelegate!
.
.
.
@IBAction func saveExerciseWasPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (checkFields() == true){
        newExercise = Exercise(name: exerciseNameField.text!, weight: Int32(weightField.text!)!, reps: Int32(numberOfRepsField.text!)!, sets: Int32(numberOfSetsField.text!)!, muscleGroupFocus: .cardio)
        newExerciseDelegate.savedExercise(newExercise: newExercise)
        dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

My receiving VC uses the following code:

```
    @IBAction func addExerciseBtnWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let newExerciseVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewExerciseVC") else { return }
    newExerciseVC.newExerciseDelegate = self // error present on this line
    presentDetail(newExerciseVC)
}
```

I'm sure it's a stupid mistake, but I'm not seeing it. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify which class it is.After the code know which class actually it is, then you can access it's public objects, methods, variables etc.

```
@IBAction func addExerciseBtnWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let newExerciseVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewExerciseVC") as? NewExerciseViewController else { return }
    newExerciseVC.newExerciseDelegate = self
    presentDetail(newExerciseVC)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing that delegate which is declared in your ViewController then you should call in the below way.

```
let childOne = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"WhatsNewViewController")  as? WhatsNewViewController
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to downcast the instantiated view controller to your custom view controller class:

```
guard let newExerciseVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewExerciseVC") as? YourViewControllerClass else { return }
newExerciseVC.newExerciseDelegate = self
```

*Also you should use a capital **E** for your protocol's name.*

Comment: My receiving class does conform to the protocol in this way, I didn't include that part in my question, my mistake. Thanks for catching the capitalization, I'm still fairly new to this and trying to get the hang of nomenclature.

Comment: The problem is, code doesn't recognize class' itself with only identifier, you have to specify which class it is.

Comment: It was the downcasting, thank you very much. This problem was driving me crazy!